# How do I stop Illustrator from snapping to pixel increments?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, cs5, snapping

I am working in Illustrator (15.0.2 (CS5) or 16.0.0 (CS6)) and when I try to move objects small distances, they snap to the nearest two pixels on some invisible grid. I can't find anything in the preferences. Here are some screen shots:

[image: move issue]

Comment: You can manually move the object to that location. Using the arrow keys will result in a 1px change, meaning if you're working on a partial-pixel level, it will move further than you may want it to.

Comment: Did you try turning off all snapping under `view`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/bug-illustrator-now-refuses-to-draw-lines-with-stroke-weight-below-1-pt/5691#5691

Comment: yup, that was one of the first few places i looked. I think it SHOULD be there... its weird that its in the transform panel!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was starting to doubt my mental health has i couldn't find a way to stop this weird behavior. You need to know that you have to check or uncheck that option for every object on your canvas. That option doesn't control the document but a single selected object. To make it even more weird, when using a shape to crop another shape, the two halves would automatically reposition themselves. To avoid this behavior in the transform window you need to deselect the "align new objects to pixel grid" option. Hope this bit of information will help someone else from going mad and

Comment: This drove me crazy almost always as there was nothing in Transform box, but I had to look in the comments to find the answer (unselect view>snap to pixel). I really don't care if it a duplicate as Scott said. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

THIS HAS BEEN UPDATED IN VERSION 23.0.1 You have to turn OFF "snap to grid" behavior. The preferences for alignment of objects are in three DIFFERENT places:

1. In VIEW menu uncheck "Snap to Point" (NOTE: this has moved in latest version to Preferences menu (see #3 below)
2. In the TRANSFORM PALETTE un-check "Align to Pixel Grid"
3. Other related options in PREFERENCES -"Disable Snap to Point"

[image]
[image]

**This has finally been updated by Adobe in the latest version of Illustrator v.23.01 and later.**

Comment: Although I heartily sympathise with your point, it does not answer the question, and is a comment at best.

Comment: I updated the post, ttok out hte commentary and clarified where the various places to edit preferences are (hidden) in Illustrator. I hope it helps people find them.

Comment: Where are the settings for this in the preferences panel ? I'm unable to find anything about this in there on CC 2015.5

Comment: There are no setting in the preferences panel for this snap-to pixel grid option...- I commented on this earlier, and was asked to take the commentary out... It's absurd that you have to set this in the TRANSFORM sub menu... (little pop up menu on the side of the incredibly small top right hand side menu button. Good luck keeping your eyesight intact.

Comment: There's one more sneaky one: you must **TURN OFF SMART GUIDES!** This also is in the **View** menu. It's easy to overlook because it's not named as a snapping feature, but *it is* a snapping feature! Smart Guides means Illustrator will randomly decide what it wants you to snap to... could be a handle, an intersection, an anchor, a path... just about anything! It tells you what it's snapping to in magenta text, so if you see this text, it means your snapping problem is caused by the stupid Smart Guides.

Comment: @Mentalist thank you! So important this point.

Answer (score 65):

For new objects, turn off "Align to Pixel Grid" on the Transform panel.

[image: transform panel]

For existing objects, select them first, then turn off Align to Pixel Grid using the checkbox at bottom of Transform panel.

Comment: This option doesn't exist in the latest version of Illustrator

Comment: @Pier see my answer below with the updated instructions for modern Illustrator versions.

Answer (score 20):

It was driving me crazy too... you can deselect the `Align to Pixel Grid` checkbox on the Transform panel (shows up on "show options"), but new objects will always retain the snapping behaviour.

To turn it of permanently, click on the flyout menu at the top right of the transform panel then uncheck `Align new objects to pixel grid`.

Phew...

Comment: Where is "show options"?

Answer (score 8):

In Illustrator 2019, the snap-to-pixel toggle has been moved to a more convenient location in the top right of the application. It is the magnet icon connected to three vertical squares.

[image: Snap to pixel in the top right of the Illustrator window]

Clicking it toggles snap-to-pixel and the dropdown arrow to its right opens an advanced options menu with additional settings.

[image: Pixel Snapping Options menu]