# How to stop snapping of slices when re-sizing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I wonder if there is any shortcut on keyboard to prevent snapping slices while re-sizing.

I am talking about slices and they are jumping not by pixel, but by distance to nearest slice edge. I've tried to disable pixel alignment on slice which had no effect at all.

I'm using Illustrator CS6.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **Snap to Point**, **Snap to Grid**, and **Align to Pixel Grid** all off, there should be no snapping. **EXCEPT** at the artboard edge.

To get rid of the snapping to the artboard edge, it's tricky....

In the **Preferences** under **Guides & Grids** set the `Snapping Tolerance` to 0. Then *turn on* Smart Guides (`View > SmartGuides`). This will disable the snapping at the artboard edge. You *must* have Smart Guides **on**. for it to stop snapping.

Answer (score 0):

Might you be referring to this: [How do I stop Illustrator from snapping to pixel increments?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/how-do-i-stop-illustrator-from-snapping-to-pixel-increments)

Just uncheck `Align New Objects to Pixel Grid`

Comment: Nope. Slices are being aligned to another slices, even when holding the alt key.

Comment: Try Unchecking Preferences>Smart Guides>Alignment Guides. Then turn ON smart guides. Don't know if this works on CS6 but works on CS5.

Comment: Even that didn't help. It appears that slices are ALWAYS snapping to any slice on current artboard. If anybody can confirm this I will stop searching...

Comment: try to create another slice very close to the one you are resizing so it will snap to it and then you will see the problem

Comment: I think it's a limitation of the tool. If you need to refine a slice's position and size further, use the transform palette. Keep in mind that slices are always quantized to the nearest pixel.

Comment: Try to align the slice at full zoom (1600% I think). That should stop snapping.

Answer (score 0):

Select the slice and use the transform panel (X,Y,W and H boxes) on the top to resize or move without snapping.