# Divide objects below issue

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am learning seamless pattern creation in Illustrator CS6. I've created some repeated pattern and divide it by rectangle using the Object-Path-Divide objects below menu. Unexpectedly, there is some dislocation of the cut shapes relatively to background which was used as a cutter - I've copied the background rectangle and put it above the all elements (without fill or stroke).
Look at the picture.

[image: cut shapes dislocation]

Is it my fault or it should be some bug within AI?

UPD1 The machine is MacBookPro and coordinates of the rectangle are as 160.466 px - could it be related to alignment issue/grid?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking at all. Was there a question there?

Comment: the brown rectangle you see on the picture was used as a cutting shape but immediately after pressing Object->Path->Divide objects below you can see than the cutting lines are shifted left and up....

Comment: Have you ensured that `Align to Pixel Grid` is not turned on for objects? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/how-do-i-stop-illustrator-from-snapping-to-pixel-increments

Comment: If you think it is matter - I'll check it

Comment: no relation to Align to Pixel Grid. was switched off; I think it is the issue with Retina display

Comment: Did you select objects before checking Align to Pixel Grid? I highly doubt it's an issue due to a retina display.

Comment: yes, of course I selected as individual object as well as all the objects of the pattern. Going banana with these issues (look for a new question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can’t post images to notes, I created an answer:

I still think it might be the pixel grid alignment.
There are two settings for the pixel grid alignment:

1. The checkbox in the Transformation panel: `Align to Pixel Grid`
2. In the Dropdown of the Transformation panel you find `Align new Objects to Textbox`

Even if the old object is not aligned to the pixel grid, it will snap to it if you divide the objects, since you create new objects from the old ones. You need to have both turned off.

Here is a screenshot in german. I can’t provide an english one, but it should show where to find it.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. after @Scott suggestion I checked both options and did not find relation to the pixel grid in both cases. I cannot reproduce the issue even Align to pixel grid is switched on in both cases.

Comment: Hmm strange behavior, I am on a rMBP too, but the only way I was able to reproduce something like that, is toggling the `Align new Objects to Pixel Grid`-option on.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that if I am too 'zoomed in' so to speak things like the pathfinder and grids and rulers will mess up. Try going backwards, and scaling your work up, a couple inches, then trying again. That might work.

For reference, I usually work at about 10x10 inch grid. I hope that helps.

Comment: Probably you're right, I also found grid related issues...