# Illustrator rotational transformation is imperfect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

So I created a simple hexagon using the polygon tool. When applying a 30° (360 / 6 / 2) rotation (to change its orientation) the anchor points are off by something what looks like a floating point rounding error.

So my question is, how do I rotate objects *perfectly*, so that the anchor points align with the grid again?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a hexagon (Polygon tool, 6 sides, 100 px radius)
2. Rotate it by 30° (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>)
3. Enable the grid and zoom in. The top and bottom anchor point will be noticeably off.

A rotation of 29.9° is actually closer to the desired result than 30°.

[image: top]
[image: bottom]

Comment: Possible fix: choosing the center/center reference point, before applying the transformation.

Comment: Disable **Align to Pixel Grid** if it is active. [**Read this . . .**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/how-do-i-stop-illustrator-from-snapping-to-pixel-increments)

Comment: It already is disabled. I am pretty certain that this is an inherent "bug" caused by the internal maths.

Comment: I'm not seeing any discrepancy. How are you rotating?

Comment: I've added images and steps to reproduce. As you can see, alignment to the pixel grid would in fact solve the problem. Therefore the link to "How do I stop Illustrator from snapping to pixel increments?" is not correct.

Comment: Based upon the images... it's *entirely* dependent upon your grid settings. You do realize the grid can be changed, right? What makes you think the grid should automatically line up to your anchors?

Comment: The only way I'm able to reproduce the problem in CC is if I have **Align to Pixel Grid** turned _on_. Everything seems perfectly aligned when the pixel alignment is off. @silvinci - can you tell us what version of Illustrator you are using?

Comment: No, it is not. The upper anchor is off to the left, while the lower anchor is off to the right. The problem is not the alignment to any grid. It is the imprecise rotation.

The hexagon is not rotated properly. I am using CS6.

Answer (score 3):

Going along with Scotts comment above, you would have to enable your grid and set your grid settings *before* creating your shapes, and thus transforming using the rotate tool.

**NOTE: Do not accept this as an answer, all credit is due to Scott. I was unable to comment due to low reputation**