# rotation target and illustrator actions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, data-visualisation, chart-design

I'm building a set of actions to help myself create pie charts, one segment create a line segment at a certain point (from the artboard center out), and the attempts to rotate it around the same point (the artboard center), copy and rotate again a different amount (I am using modals to set the exact angle each time), and then again twice more. The issue is that each time the segment rotates the rotation origin changes as it is relative to the line segment, rather than the global space of the art-board.

**Is there a way to either

A) Create a static rotation origin (perhaps tied to another object)**

**or B) calculate the new rotation origin based on the amount of rotation within the action itself.**

Any suggestions?
Also, open to alternative solutions rather than actions, I need to create a large number of uniform pie charts with varying segment values (the chart tool winds up taking far longer)

[image: current result using rotation of -25 each, alongside action]

Target final product (currently I am creating these with the parts of the action that work and doing the rotation portion manually)
[image: Target Final Product]

Comment: Isn't the rotation always from the object's center?

Comment: By default yes, the rotation is from the object's center. However, I want the rotation target to be the artboard center (typically accomplished by R + holding alt to move the rotation target). Although the action records the center point, it seems to be getting modified somehow.

Comment: Furthermore, The action panel appropriately displays the rotation origin as "Origin DX: 0pt Origin DY: 52.58pt" (the correct center point of the artboard) however, the target moves somewhere new each time I run the action, often in both an X and Y dimension

Comment: Sounds odd, can you [edit your question and add the script](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/73834/edit)? or describe what you recorded in the actions?

Comment: just uploaded a screenshot of the action

Comment: [does this help?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31423/illustrator-rotational-transformation-is-imperfect)

Comment: I wish...Align to pixel grid/snapping are both off as I'm not doing anything that requires it at the moment.

Comment: Going to reset my prefs (why didn't I do this before) and see what happens, maybe I just got unlucky....Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hey @Luciano, updated my question after tinkering some more, would love your input!

Comment: This would be quite easy to script, in either jsx (extendscript a javascript dialect), EPS or COM. You up for the task?

Comment: I am - I have a bit of JS experience under my belt, and have messed with some .svg code, any chance you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: My first instinct was to select all and rotate everything, since you are working within a circle.. but I'm getting the same seemingly random origin, even though I didnt set an origin (which should default to the center). Very strange

Comment: @Cai I can't select all and rotate everything as I specifically need to rotate the duplicated line segments in order to correctly divide the circle into the different segments later in the script (after the third rotation). That is quite a strange result though, I'll have see if I can recreate it, may hold some answers.

Comment: Well im floating in a lake so i dont have a illustrator at hand right now but, [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37998/how-to-create-a-vector-curve-programmatically/38010#38010) for some idea on how to get started. Tough for a action youbcould use the built in graph tool and use it as a cookie cutter.

Comment: @joojaa enjoy the lake! Thanks for the tip, trying to avoid the graph tool because...that thing is terrible

Comment: Yes but remenber your just using it to generate the lines and ditch the result after that

Comment: ah good point, I'll try to approach it from that direction too and see where I land. Come to think of it, that would add more flexibility to the result as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use the transform *effect* rather than a regular transform, which will let you set the transform origin from the dialog. Actions won't record effects so you will need to use the *Insert Menu Item...* option from the Actions panel's dropdown and select the effect.

Since the transform is an effect rather than an actual transform you may want to expand appearance on everything at the end of your action.

Here is a quick example using transform effects:

[image]

Comment: fantastic! Can't test just now but it would seem that this will work wonderfully