# Objects not snapping correctly. (Overshooting or undershooting target)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, snapping

I have a rectangle that should be snapping to the lines of the other rectangles on my artboard, but it keeps overshooting the mark. Can anyone advise on how to get it to snap the other objects lines correctly?

Ai version: CC2014. OS Mac: 10.9.5.

[image: Snapping to random point, not other object.]

[image: Snap Options.]

[image: Pixel grid options.]

Comment: Might [this post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/how-do-i-stop-illustrator-from-snapping-to-pixel-increments) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because there is one more object behind the rectangle, you want to snap with.
If this is not the case, go to preferences ---

**Preferences> uncheck select object by path only**

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check that you don't have the option "Align New Objects to Pixel Grid" checked in the Transform panel (under the submenu in the upper right hand corner). See the image below for further explanation on its placement.

[image: How to disable "align new objects to pixel grid"]

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with the default template "Common" - when I went to any other template it seemed fine, but for whatever reason I couldn't get that template to snap right.

Comment: Hello Miles, welcome to GDSE. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.