# How to stop Adobe Illustrator's minus front Pathfinder command from altering sizes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

I am trying to use minus front on a grouping of objects (object 1) that I want to cut out of object 2. But when I click minus front, it actually changes half the group shapes. Any idea why? I've never had this happened before.

[image]

Comment: Is Align to Pixel grid on?

Comment: Thanks so much Scott! That's exactly what the issue was.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever shapes change in unexpected manners you need to check the **Align To Pixel Grid** setting for the object. Most often, that is the culprit.

[This question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/how-do-i-stop-illustrator-from-snapping-to-pixel-increments) will be of more assistance.