# How to display spacing information between the two elements in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, layers

When I hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in Photoshop it displays spacing information between the layer that I have selected and other nearby layers.

Does Adobe Illustrator a similar function to this?

[image: example from photoshop]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything identical (would be great if there is though), but you can achieve something equivalent by:

1. Turn on smart guides (from view menu or toggle with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).
2. Move the second object so that it touches and the smart guides tell you it `intersect`s with the other object. This snaps to the intersect so the distance between the edges is exactly 0. Drop it there.
3. Start moving it again, and a grey box appears next to the object showing how far you've moved it on the X axis (`dX:`) and Y axis
   (`dY:`). Since the objects were exactly touching when you started moving them (distance
   was 0), this will equal the objects' new distance.

Be aware that, unlike Photoshop, [`pixel align` is optional in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/how-do-i-stop-illustrator-from-snapping-to-pixel-increments) so with it disabled you might see things moved 14.42px for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Mac you can do a key command: command-control-shift-4. This is for the screenshot tool that allows you to select a specific portion of the screen and take a pic. It also had X and Y coordinates. So you can use it to find the width or height and then hit escape to get out.

Comment: You only need cmd+shift+4, the ctrl saves it to the clipboard whereas without saves it to a file but since you're not worried about the actual screenshot the key less is better. Great tip though!

Answer (score 2):

As of now, there is still no feature to get the spacing in illustrator.

There is a plugin by [Astute Graphics](https://astutegraphics.com/shop/), called [VectorScribe](https://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/) which including a Measuring tool, it has multiple other very useful tools, (I encourage you to try out the free trial)

---

> [image]

---

You can also convert the measurements panel into actual text (clicking on the down arrow of the box) - (then to a vector shape if necessary <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) which can help if you're sharing the file with someone who doesn't have the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

One method, easier than the Measure tool which doesn't snap to paths or anchors, is to use the Line Tool  <kbd>\</kbd>  instead.

Enable Smart Guides, draw a line while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to constrain it horizontally or vertically, and its width or height will show in the tool options along the top. Then *Undo* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to remove it.

[image]

Obviously this will only work for horizontal or vertical measurements.