# Path and Fill doesn't line up, anyone got any solutions?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, fill

I can't see to work out why the fill within the path doesn't line up with it. I have checked to see if I have any transform effect applied to your path, which there isn't. There is no stroke on this image, it is just a fill that seems to be a couple pixels below the path. There is no brush stroke applied as its just a fill.

So I am pretty stumped, here is the image to get an idea of what it looks like.

Thanks for your time guys, any possible solutions would be greatly appreciated!

[image: ![Image of the fill]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxBAs.jpg)

Comment: Is this Illustrator or what? have you checked Align to Pixels? How zoomed in is this, how small is the object, have you tried restarting the software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop Illustrator from snapping to pixel increments?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/how-do-i-stop-illustrator-from-snapping-to-pixel-increments)  and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60511/why-the-paths-doesnt-match-with-the-stroke-in-illustrator-cs6?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shot doesn't show a lot and your path line that you have selected isn't the line the stroke is applied to or it would follow the line. However, do you a brush stroke applied?     It looks like you might have a calligraphy angled brush applied which will cause that look. Otherwise maybe a layering issue. If the green line is the line the stroke is applied to, it looks like the brown box is covering up your line.

Comment: Sorry it's not that clear. There is no stroke on this image, it is just a fill that seems to be a couple pixels below the path. There is no brush stroke applied as its just a fill.

Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: would you be able to share a link to the file?  it's hard to tell what is going on.