# My vector shapes break when I make them small

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, resize

I'm doing a one shape logo on Ai. I merge the shapes and they are just one shape. But when I make them small, they 'break' they are not even a logo anymore.

How do I avoid this?

[image]

Comment: This is probably an Align To Pixel Grid problem. Why oh why did they make that the default... http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/how-do-i-stop-illustrator-from-snapping-to-pixel-increments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure before merging two shapes to expand them. Then go to Edit>Preferences>General and uncheck the option "Scale Strokes & Effects" if it's checked.

Comment: it wasnt but when I make expand I have checked fill and strokes is that correct?

Comment: Yes, when you expand an object you should check fill and strokes (unless you want to achieve something else). But in general the option  "Scale Strokes & Effects" should be unchecked (unless, again you want to achieve something else).

Comment: It was so i dont think this is the problem :S