# Adobe Illustrator: Objects slide when scaled down

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, snapping

I've searched forum and I can't seem to find solution to my problem (or even questions related to it).

I use Illustrator CC and I run into this problem.

[image]

Note: I have used no strokes, only four separate shapes plus another one as a stroke underneath all. Now if I try to scale it down, let's say, four times the size, I get strange results. As if the shapes move around when scaled down.

Then, if I try to fix the problem by scaling down the underlying shape, it snaps way off the desired position.

I have turned off **Align new objects to pixel grid**.

I apologize if this question was posted earlier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop Illustrator from snapping to pixel increments?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/how-do-i-stop-illustrator-from-snapping-to-pixel-increments)

Comment: ITs not enough to turn " Align new objects to pixel grid" foo you need to also turn it off for allready created objects separately. PS: i never use the align to pixel grid option for anything sincer its more trouble than worth if I want to snap to pixels i can allways adjust my snapping grid.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any effects applied to your artwork: e.g., Roughen, Tweak, Twist?

If so, you may need to expand the original shapes before scaling—**Menu > Object > Expand Appearance**.

Answer (score 0):

What tool do you use when scaling your illustration?

It might be a "Transform Each" problem.
Try these two approaches and see if they make a difference:

1. Object -> Transform -> Scale...
2. Object -> Transform -> Transform Each...