# Illustrator is unable to make a horizontal line thinner than 1pt

Tags: adobe-illustrator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug: Illustrator now refuses to draw lines with stroke weight below 1 pt](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/bug-illustrator-now-refuses-to-draw-lines-with-stroke-weight-below-1-pt)

On my Illustrator CS5.5 I have the strange behaviour that when I make a perfect horizontal line, the stroke weight has a minimal value of 1pt. I can set it to 0.5pt, but it will jump back.
If I make a non-horizontal line and set its stroke weight to a value <1pt, everything is OK. The moment I make that line horizontal the weight jumps back to 1pt. It is possible though to set the weight to 0pt, however this renders the line invisible.

Is there a setting I can change to avoid this behaviour or is there some special reason for this?

Comment: Is a duplicate except that I only have this problem with horizontal lines. From the other question it is not clear if it applies to all lines, or just horizontal ones. But I don't think it's enough different for a new question so mine can be closed.

Comment: It's the same issue and the same solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncheck **Align to Pixel Grid** on the Transform Panel.

This feature was introduced in Creative Suite 5 in order to allow users to make sharper, crisper graphics for screen presentation (web, mobile) by ensuring strokes always fall on exact pixels and therefore reducing the amount of anti-aliasing applied to straight strokes or edges.

Comment: Yeah, this is it. In addition: The default behaviour when creating objects can be set when creating a new document.